# FromDMS conversion within a Mathematica Dataset

Tags: dataset

I have a simple dataset for which I am attempting to modify so that values for two columns, entitled “LATITUDE” and “LONGITUDE” can be converted from a Deg-Min-Sec format, expressed as a String (ie “9°44'N”), into a decimal format suitable for geocoding (ie "9.7333").

A subsample is given below:

{<|"SPECIES" -> "Pontinus moseri", "COUNTRY" -> "COSTA RICA", 
  "CATALOG NUMBER" -> "CAS 60423", "NUMBER OF SPECIMENS" -> 1, 
  "SIZE RANGE in mm" -> 156.1, "LOT REMARKS" -> "", 
  "LATITUDE-LONGITUDE" -> "", "LATITUDE" -> "", "LONGITUDE" -> "", 
  "LOCALITY" -> "no precise locality", "BOTTOM" -> "", "DEPTH" -> "", 
  "GEAR" -> "", "FIELD NUMBER" -> "FHB 11-XII-73A", 
  "EXPEDITION" -> "", "VESSEL" -> "", "CRUISE" -> "", "STATION" -> "",
   "COLLECTOR" -> "F. H. Berry", "TIME" -> "", 
  "DATE" -> "11 Dec 1973", 
  "ACCESSION NUMBER" -> "Acc. 1974-V:31"|>, <|"SPECIES" -> 
   "Pontinus moseri", "COUNTRY" -> "COSTA RICA", 
  "CATALOG NUMBER" -> "CAS 60632", "NUMBER OF SPECIMENS" -> 2, 
  "SIZE RANGE in mm" -> "91.9-94.1", "LOT REMARKS" -> "", 
  "LATITUDE-LONGITUDE" -> "9[Degree]34'N, 84[Degree]48'43\"W", 
  "LATITUDE" -> "9[Degree]34'N", 
  "LONGITUDE" -> "84[Degree]48'43\"W", 
  "LOCALITY" -> "Gulf of Nicoya, off Quepos, Zone 21", "BOTTOM" -> "",
   "DEPTH" -> "150 fa [274 m]", "GEAR" -> "", 
  "FIELD NUMBER" -> "FBH 13-XII-73C", "EXPEDITION" -> "", 
  "VESSEL" -> "", "CRUISE" -> "", "STATION" -> "", 
  "COLLECTOR" -> "F. H. Berry", "TIME" -> "0620 hrs", 
  "DATE" -> "13 Dec 1973", 
  "ACCESSION NUMBER" -> ""|>, <|"SPECIES" -> "Pontinus moseri", 
  "COUNTRY" -> "COSTA RICA", "CATALOG NUMBER" -> "CAS 204797", 
  "NUMBER OF SPECIMENS" -> 1, "SIZE RANGE in mm" -> 84.2, 
  "LOT REMARKS" -> "[ex CAS 60419]", 
  "LATITUDE-LONGITUDE" -> "9[Degree]34'N, 84[Degree]53'W", 
  "LATITUDE" -> "9[Degree]34'N", "LONGITUDE" -> "84[Degree]53'W", 
  "LOCALITY" -> "Peninsula de Osa, Zone 27", "BOTTOM" -> "", 
  "DEPTH" -> "120-127 fa [219-232 m]", "GEAR" -> "bottom trawl", 
  "FIELD NUMBER" -> "FHB 9-XII-73", "EXPEDITION" -> "", 
  "VESSEL" -> "", "CRUISE" -> "", "STATION" -> "", 
  "COLLECTOR" -> "F. H. Berry", "TIME" -> "", "DATE" -> "9 Dec 1973", 
  "ACCESSION NUMBER" -> "Acc. 1979-IV:23"|>, <|"SPECIES" -> 
   "Pontinus moseri", "COUNTRY" -> "COSTA RICA", 
  "CATALOG NUMBER" -> "LACM 30720-4", "NUMBER OF SPECIMENS" -> 3, 
  "SIZE RANGE in mm" -> "115.4-148.2", "LOT REMARKS" -> "", 
  "LATITUDE-LONGITUDE" -> 
   "[ca. 9[Degree]23'30\"N, 84[Degree]15'00\"W]", 
  "LATITUDE" -> "9[Degree]23'30\"N", 
  "LONGITUDE" -> "84[Degree]15'00\"W", 
  "LOCALITY" -> "Puntarenas, Punta Quepos", "BOTTOM" -> "", 
  "DEPTH" -> "", "GEAR" -> "", "FIELD NUMBER" -> "", 
  "EXPEDITION" -> "", "VESSEL" -> "", "CRUISE" -> "", "STATION" -> "",
   "COLLECTOR" -> "R. T. Nishimoto", "TIME" -> "", 
  "DATE" -> "16 Jul 1969", "ACCESSION NUMBER" -> ""|>}

with the above imported as

```
dataset = Import["Pontinus_moseri_locality_data.csv","Dataset",HeaderLines-> 1]
```

and as converted by

```
assoc = Normal[dataset];

and

Take[assoc, {9, 15, 2}]
```

to get the subsample given above.

Interestingly, if instead I import from an *.XLSX file using the following command:

```
dataset = Import["Pontinus_moseri_locality_data.xlsx", "Dataset",  
HeaderLines -> 1]
```

Normal does not return the association but rather the displayed dataset table, which looks identical to that using the .csv import given above, but instead has
a Head[dataset] as List. I am unsure why this happens as the tables seem identical with the same displayed scrollable MMA format give for Dataset objects.

In any event, from within this dataset object (via csv) I attempt to make the conversion using an overloaded function to handle the cases for value = Null or value = "", as follows:

```
latlongConvert[x_ /; x != Null] := 
 Module[{a}, a = ToString[N[FromDMS[ToString[x]], 5]]; Return [a]]

latlongConvert[x_ /; SameQ[x, ""]] := Module[{a}, a = ""; Return [a]]

latlongConvert[x_ /; SameQ[x, Null]] := Module[{a}, a = Null; Return [a]]

moseriLocalityDataMod1 = dataset[All, {"LATITUDE" -> latlongConvert, 
 "LONGITUDE" -> latlongConvert}]
```

Although the code executes with no errors, the conversions do not take place, with values within the Dataset object instead being replaced by the called object (ie latlongConvert["9°44'N"] etc.) but not evaluating to "9.7333"

Nonetheless, executing the expression

```
ToString[N[FromDMS[ToString[9°44'N]],5]]
```

returns “9.7333" as expected.

**What do I have to change to get the conversion to execute correctly, with the correct decimal format being substituted for the original deg min sec format within the dataset?**

Comment: The format of data does not make much sense. For instance, your quotes are "curly quotes" whereas MMA would only recognize "regular" quotes to delimit strings. Could you please paste *exactly* the content of `dataset` instead?

Comment: Let's start with syntax: Try `Clear[latitudeConvert]; latitudeConvert[x_String] := ToString[N[FromDMS[ToString[x]], 5]]` for starters. Notice that you cannot write `Return a`; you could use `Return[a]`, but you actually almost never need Return in this context.

Comment: Furthermore, the two convert functions are the same, are they not? So just write a single `convert` function that works for both.

Comment: Marco, I have made the suggested changes, with cut/paste using output directly from MMA rather than the data I previously gave using a wordprocessor, which used the "curly" double quotes (but same key).  Full Dataset too big to pass here, hence the subsample.

Comment: FOUND THE ANSWER! by just replacing the first function with  latlongConvert[x_ /; StringLength[x] > 1] := 
 Module[{a}, a = ToString[N[FromDMS[ToString[x]], 5]]; Return [a]].  Following up using your suggestions was all that was needed.  Thanks Marco.

Comment: Only question now outstanding is why the two versions of Input (csv vs xlsx) produce different results.

Answer (score 1):

Following MarcoB's suggestions to their logical conclusion the First Overloaded function works.  The problem arises from the different structure of the output from the two lines

```
dataset = Import["Pontinus_moseri_locality_data.csv","Dataset",HeaderLines-> 1]
```

which generates has a Head[dataset] = Dataset and

```
dataset = Import["Pontinus_moseri_locality_data.xlsx", "Dataset",  
HeaderLines -> 1] (this does not work and Head[dataset] = List)
```

and making two additional changes to the original code:
1) overloading the function to account for Null and "" in the data as shown above, and 
2) changing the original conditional on the function to /; StringLength[x]>1 rather than /; x!=Null.